# Add a "reference line" to a plotly polar plot in Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I have created a polar plot (in Python) from a dataframe with one categorical variable and one continuous variable using plotly express (v. 5.19) using `px.line_polar`. It is exactly what I want (see following image).

I would like to add some "reference lines" to this plot. Since it is a polar plot, the reference lines will be circles (centered at the origin of the polar plot).

[image]

I've tried adding shapes to the plot using the methods described [here](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/), but can't seem to figure out how to get the circle in the center of the polar plot - I guess I don't know what the center coordinates of the plot are on the "paper".

Comment: See Example 1 in this link : https://www.scaler.com/topics/matplotlib/polar-plot-matplotlib/

Comment: Thanks @iFlo. Those instructions look like they will work great for matplotlib. I am wondering how to do the "same thing" with plotly.

Comment: This seems to match your needs better : https://community.plotly.com/t/shapes-on-a-polar-plot-is-it-posible/29155

Comment: You could add another variable in your df to add a second trace to the figure, having a fixed `r` value for all `theta`, use `line_shape='spine'` to obtain a nice circle. If you need more details please provide a mwe.